How to detect mouse leave event when the mouse left button is hold down?
i tried this but it's not working. the check is never true and it's never get inside.
private void pictureBoxImageToCrop_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the right mouse button is being held down
    if ((Control.MouseButtons & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        // Perform the desired action when the right mouse button is held down
        isDrawing = false;
        // Additional actions can be added here if needed
    }
    isDrawing = false;
}


MouseLeave fires after MouseUp (apparently) ... therefore, "it's in the queue". (You may also start getting into things like mouse capture).

Use MouseMove. The control will capture events while the mouse button is held even if you leave its bounds, just check the mouse coordinates against the control's bounds. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076217/how-can-i-check-on-picturebox1-mouse-leave-event-if-the-user-is-in-mouse-down-ev?rq=2

using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class PictureBoxCropExample : Form
{
    private PictureBox _pictureBox;
    private Point _startPoint;
    private Rectangle _cropRectangle;
    private bool _isMouseDown = false;

    public PictureBoxCropExample()
    {
        // Initialize form
        this.Size = new Size(500, 500);

        // Initialize PictureBox
        _pictureBox = new PictureBox();
        _pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.placeholder_image; // Replace with your image
        _pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        _pictureBox.Size = new Size(250, 250);
        _pictureBox.Location = new Point((this.ClientSize.Width - _pictureBox.Width) / 2,
                                        (this.ClientSize.Height - _pictureBox.Height) / 2);
        _pictureBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

        // Subscribe to mouse events for crop functionality
        _pictureBox.MouseDown += PictureBox_MouseDown;
        _pictureBox.MouseMove += PictureBox_MouseMove;
        _pictureBox.MouseUp += PictureBox_MouseUp;
        _pictureBox.Paint += PictureBox_Paint;

        // Add PictureBox to form
        this.Controls.Add(_pictureBox);
    }

    private void PictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            _isMouseDown = true;
            _startPoint = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void PictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isMouseDown)
        {
            int x = Math.Min(_startPoint.X, e.X);
            int y = Math.Min(_startPoint.Y, e.Y);
            int width = Math.Abs(_startPoint.X - e.X);
            int height = Math.Abs(_startPoint.Y - e.Y);

            _cropRectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            _pictureBox.Invalidate(); // Redraw PictureBox
        }
    }

    private void PictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && _isMouseDown)
        {
            _isMouseDown = false;

            // Perform crop operation based on _cropRectangle
            if (_cropRectangle.Width > 0 && _cropRectangle.Height > 0)
            {
                Bitmap originalImage = (Bitmap)_pictureBox.Image;
                Bitmap croppedImage = new Bitmap(_cropRectangle.Width, _cropRectangle.Height);

                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(croppedImage))
                {
                    g.DrawImage(originalImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, croppedImage.Width, croppedImage.Height),
                                _cropRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }

                // Display cropped image in PictureBox
                _pictureBox.Image = croppedImage;
            }
        }
    }

    private void PictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isMouseDown)
        {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, _cropRectangle);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new PictureBoxCropExample());
    }
}


this is working for me.  you checking didn't work.  Point NewPoint = e.Location;
if (!((PictureBox)sender).ClientRectangle.Contains(NewPoint))
{
isDrawing = false;
return;
}
